# View a log of actions on Azure Devops build pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

**Context**

In our  Azure Devops, we have a build pipeline, where we keep some builds using the "retain this build" action.

It turns out some of the builds that should have been kept were deleted.
It is most probably the result of a bad manipulation on our part, but I don't know where to look for a log of the actions on the builds, to check if it is a bug or a misusage.

**Question**

Is there a log of the actions taken on the builds of a build pipeline ?

I'm looking for something which would list :

- [date time] [user] started a build on this pipeline
- [date time] [user] canceled build xyz on this pipeline
- [date time] [user] modified the piepeline definition  `# this one is displayed in the GUI`
- [date time] [user] added/removed some tags on build xyz
- [date time] [user] explicitly removed build xyz from this pipeline
- [date time] [user] added/removed the flag "retain" on build xyz
- and other actions accessible through the GUI or the API ...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/audit/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/auditing-for-azure-devops-is-now-in-public-preview/

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. Can you post this as an answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Azure DevOps Audit features are currently in preview](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/auditing-for-azure-devops-is-now-in-public-preview/). They should capture the most important events that impact changes,  permissions and retention.

There is a [REST-API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/audit/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) which allows you to query the data in case the standard functionality doesn't  tell you what you need.

Azure DevOps Auditing retains a limited amount of data. It will be possible to steam events to a more permanent store in the future.

[This Quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/azure-devops-auditing?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) indicates how to grant access to the auditing logs, and how to view these logs through Azure Devops GUI.

Comment: thanks ! This allowed me to file the following bug : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/818506/build-pipeline-retained-build-has-disappeared.html